# Mongodb NULL Instead of delete

Tags: mongodb

I managed to found out how to delete field but I have a problem It doesn't really delete it it just set it to NULL.

```
db.user.update({'username': 'mezo', 'person': {'$in' : ['masidnadi241479214']}}, {'$unset': {'person.$': 1}})
```

My structure is something like that:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ff14c7461d69af811000000"),
    "confirmed" : true,
    "person" : [
            null,
            null,
            "194724198274192",
            "3"
    ],
    "username" : "mezo"
```

}

Comment: Why don't you try with the command $pull, which removes all occurrences of value from field, if field is an array and you can get ride of the annoying null :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this behaviour is to be expected. To remove null elements from the array, run

```
 db.collection.update(query, {$pull: {'person': null}})
```

after that $unset operation.